# TS file not playing hls.js

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg

Need some help. Video loads in browser but never starts playing. I'm using hls.js to stream m3u8 playlist to the browser. And I use FFmpeg to create ts and m3u8 files.

For FFmpeg :

```
./ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://user:password@ipaddress/axis-media/media.amp -vcodec copy -hls_time 4 -hls_list_size 4 -hls_wrap 4 -start_number 1 -y test.m3u8
```

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@latest"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
     <video id="video" height="800px" width="1200px"></video>
  <body>

  <script>
     var video = document.getElementById('video');
     if(Hls.isSupported()){
        var hls = new Hls();
        hls.loadSource('/images/live/test.m3u8');
        hls.attachMedia(video);
        hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED,function() {
              video.play();
         });
      }
      else if (video.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl')){
         video.src = '/images/live/test.m3u8';
         video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata',function() {
              video.play();
         });
      }
   </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Depending on the browser you use, it might be just a matter of blocking autoplay. If you add player controls to your video element <video id="video" height="800px" width="1200px" controls></video>, reload the page and press play, does it help?

Comment: Even I add a control of the video tag, it doesn't play the playlist.

Comment: What browser are you testing this with? Is there any error in its console? You said that your stream loads, but if you try it in hls.js demo player directly [here](https://video-dev.github.io/hls.js/latest/demo/), can you confirm it plays? Note that the stream needs to be delivered via https for the demo page to work.

Comment: There's no error in the console. I'm using google chrome latest version. Yes, it loads by checking in the network by inspecting.

Comment: I post this issue on github. @tbucher please check this https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/issues/2346

Comment: Have you tried the stream in the hls.js demo player or any other player? Just checking the network tab is not sufficient. Based on that image you provided it seems that the stream is not even being decoded. Can you provide console output from FFmpeg? Also, the FFmpeg commandline is not optimal as it is continually overwriting 4 segments over and over again and delayed players might be asking for wrong content because of that. Better approach might be replacing `-hls_wrap 4` (deprecated) with `-hls_flags delete_segments`, but it shouldn't be the immediate reason for your issue.

Comment: Other than that, the HTML code you are using is otherwise working fine, my own hls stream loads and plays from it without problem.

Comment: I tried my stream in native hls but it didn't work. And when I tried the ts segment with vlc player, it plays perfectly.

Comment: Actually, it works in the past few weeks but now it's not working. I didn't touch or change the code.

Comment: @tbucher can you suggest me a command line for FFmpeg hls streaming?

Comment: As I said, replacing `-hls_wrap 4` in your commandline with `-hls_flags delete_segments` should be enough to make the stream more robust. Your commandline should be then perfectly usable. But you haven't provided FFmpeg console log, so we still don't know the root cause of your particular issue, please post it here. Also try to restart the camera if you have access to it to rule out timestamp issues. Alternatively, try to re-encode the stream by using `-c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -vf format=yuv420p` instead of `-vcodec copy` just to rule out that the input is somehow suddenly incompatible.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas @tbucher I've already solved my problem. I just change the -vcodec copy to -c:v libx264. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the ffmpeg command line to :
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://user:password@ip_address/axis-media/media.amp -y -s 854x480 -codec:v libx264 -b:v 800000 -hls_time 4 -hls_list_size 4 -hls_wrap 4 start_number 0 test.m3u8

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code.

1. the play need the blowser allow the audio auto display

   > NotAllowedError: The play method is not allowed by the user agent or
   >   the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied
   >   permission.
2. the hls.js cannot access it's map file

   > request failed with status 404
   >   URL：hls.min.js.map

Just change it to a workable cdn

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
     <video id="video" height="800px" width="1200px"></video>
  <body>

  <script>
     var video = document.getElementById('video');
     if(Hls.isSupported()){
        var hls = new Hls();
        hls.loadSource('http://vfile1.grtn.cn/2018/1542/0254/3368/154202543368.ssm/154202543368.m3u8');
        hls.attachMedia(video);
        hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED,function() {
              video.play();
         });
      }
      else if (video.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl')){
         video.src = 'http://vfile1.grtn.cn/2018/1542/0254/3368/154202543368.ssm/154202543368.m3u8';
         video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata',function() {
              video.play();
         });
      }
   </script>
</html>
```